# Bungeecord ignore the large and lower cases

Tags: java, string, permissions, minecraft, bungeecord

How to ignore the large and lower cases in the below code:

```
public static boolean hasPermission(String name) {
    for (String group : ProxyServer.getInstance().getConfigurationAdapter().getGroups(name)) {
        if (ProxyServer.getInstance().getConfigurationAdapter().getPermissions(group).contains("kick.bypass")) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

I use this method to check the permissions because `name` is not a proxied player.

For example I use the command on the Player:

`/ban Peter` the player isn't banned

`/ban PetER` the player is banned because the name PetER is not in the Config.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **.toLowerCase** on the string and the command.

To elaborate let's say you do /ban Peter. Your plugin takes it and turns it into lowercase and checks if the player is into the config. But before it checks if it's in the config it turns the value in the config to lower case. So both values are lowercase and it all works out. :)

You can also use **.toUpperCase** if you like.